# error with InviteToChannelRequest (telethon)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to invite people to my channel using telethon (InviteToChannelRequest)

```
api_id = 12345
api_hash = '123abc123'
client = TelegramClient('test1', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

client(InviteToChannelRequest(
    -100********,
    ['87654321']
))
```

i using @getmyid_bot to find id of my channel: Forwarded from chat: -100********
and i have an error:

```
ValueError: Could not find the input entity for PeerUser(user_id=100********) (PeerUser). Please read https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/entities.html to find out more details.
```